# Creating a dropdown in using Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, drop-down-menu

So I currently have two models with the following associations:

```
class DnsRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true

  has_one :ip_address

  attr_accessible :name
end

class IpAddress < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :ipv4, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true, :length => { :maximum => 45 }
  validates :ipv6, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true, :length => { :maximum => 45 }

  belongs_to :dns_record

  attr_accessible :ipv4, :ipv6
end
```

In the dns_record view (/app/views/dns_records), when I am on the create a new dns_recrod page, I want a dropdown selection of currently existing ip_addresses. This way, when I create a new dns_record, it will have with it an associated ip_address_id.

I'm very new to ruby and rails, so if anyone can point me in the right direction, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you certain about your associations? Would DnSRecord belongs_to :ip_address AND IpAddress has_one :dns_record be acceptable? If so, you can handle this easily with the collection_select helper.

Comment: have you solved your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Twitter bootstrap is right for you.
http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#dropdowns

It'll get you started and show you how to incorporate a dropdown into your rails app. Its does all the heavy lifting for you. Enjoy.

Comment: There are other solutions also, you could create it yourself using JQuery but if you don't like Bootstrap, there are alternatives like foundation or html5 boilerplate projects

Comment: I'm talking about the <select> tag, not a dropdown menu. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you have your associations exactly the way you want them.  From your question, I'm assuming you'd want:

```
class DnsRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true
  belongs_to :ip_address
end

class IpAddress < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :ipv4, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true, :length => { :maximum => 45 }
  validates :ipv6, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true, :length => { :maximum => 45 }
  has_one :dns_record
  attr_accessible :ipv4, :ipv6
end
```

If so, then you can use the collection_select to set your ip_address for the dns_record object. example:

```
<% form_for @dns_record do |f| %>
  <%= f.collection_select :ip_address_id, IpAddress.all, :id, :ipv4 %>
<% end %>
```

The above assumes that you're working with a @dns_record object and your dns_records table has an ip_address_id (FK) column.  This will also use the value in ip_addresses.ipv4 as the value in the drop down.